# Mod_rewrite cross domain extensions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple domain extensions and have therefore written a mod_rewrite that takes rewrites the URL back to a .com setting the original extension as a query parameter:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.(co\.)?(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://api.example.com/$1?l=%2 [QSA,R]
```

This works fine, my problem is that I need the internal redirect to be always to `api.example.com/index.php` so that for instance:
`api.example.fr/v1/users =>` 
 
`(ext) api.example.com/v1/users/?l=fr`

 `(int) api.example.com/index.php`
I've been messing about with this for some time now and would appreciate any help on the matter...
 Many Regards

Comment: So you want **both** external redirection (as already happening) and internal rewrite as well?

Comment: Yeah, how can i achieve that? Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried for the internal redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for `api.example.fr` and `api.example.com` are same.

You can have your code like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.(co\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://api.example.com/$1?l=%2 [QSA,R,L]

# add missing /v1/ if needed
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^((?!v1/).*)$ /v1/$1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$    
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php) /index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: I would actually also like that addresses without 'v1' are appended this automatically.. I have tried using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![v|V]\d+` `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v1/$1 [QSA,R,L]` but it seems to disturb the general rewrite, would you know how to implement this?

Comment: So you want: `api.example.fr/users` to `api.example.com/v1/users/?l=fr` ?